# How to read CSV and EXL file using Django rest framework and store it into the model

Tags: python, django, csv, django-rest-framework

I have gone through several blogs and youtube tutorials to understand how to read and store CSV and xls file data in a database and avoid duplication of the data, but I did not get a proper result, can someone please tell me how to achieve this using inbuilt CSV and openxls module.

Thank You

Comment: you just need django to get the files from rest api and save it in the database. you have to read the data from restapi and use these library to do there work and use django for saving it in database

Comment: @sahasrara62 can you share some references, if possible?

Comment: @Roharsh Joy where are you reading the file from?

Comment: @sahasrara62 from frontend

Comment: @RoharshJoy from front end take file, send it to back end process it there

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use pandas for reading CSV and Excel files.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html
After getting data frame, you can manipulate with all rows.